# jPlayer - How to make a button to slide and seek progress

Tags: javascript, jplayer

jPlayer has a seekBar, with it's own built in functionality, however I want a seeker similar to the picture below.  So you would hold down and drag the circle to seek through the song.

[image]

After researching it, it appears there is nothing built into jPlayer for that. If that is true, is there perhaps a way to set the current song progress dynamically?  Then I can build my own seeker function and set the progress depending where the slider was released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/Ls8p90y9/4/

This has a ball to seek with. Seems exactly what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: "Bubble",
                mp3: "http://jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3"
            });
        },
        timeupdate: function(event) {
            $("#jp_container_1 .jp-ball").css("left",event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute + "%");
        },
        swfPath: "https://rawgit.com/happyworm/jPlayer/tree/master/dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: true,
        toggleDuration: true
    });


    /* Modern Seeking */

    var timeDrag = false; /* Drag status */
    $('.jp-play-bar').mousedown(function (e) {
        timeDrag = true;
        updatebar(e.pageX);
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        if (timeDrag) {
            timeDrag = false;
            updatebar(e.pageX);
        }
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        if (timeDrag) {
            updatebar(e.pageX);
        }
    });

    //update Progress Bar control
    var updatebar = function (x) {

        var progress = $('.jp-progress');
        var maxduration = $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer.duration; //audio duration
        console.log(maxduration);
        var position = x - progress.offset().left; //Click pos
        var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();

        //Check within range
        if (percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;
        }
        if (percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0;
        }

        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("playHead", percentage);

        //Update progress bar and video currenttime
        $('.jp-ball').css('left', percentage+'%');
        $('.jp-play-bar').css('width', percentage + '%');
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer.currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
    };

});
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a boss.

Comment: @Samir Yeah, I know it